# Laravel skipping "required" file validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

i'm having a problem with laravel 8, i really don't know what i'm doing wrong but the files are skipping the required rule in the validation, i'm sending the form with an array of names and files, and executing the validation in the controller:

```
 public function store(StoreExamenRequest $examenRequest, StoreResultadoRequest $resultadoRequest)
 {
     $validacionExamen = $examenRequest->validated();
     $validacionResultado = $resultadoRequest-validated();
```

the part that is not validating the file is `$resultadoRequest-validated();` This is the content of `StoreResultadoRequest`

```
class StoreResultadoRequest extends FormRequest {
 public function authorize()
 {
     return true;
 }

 public function rules()
 {
     $this->redirect => url()->previous();

     return [
         'NombreResultado.*' => 'required|string',
         'ArchivoResultado.*' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf|max:1024',
     ];
 }

 public function messages()
 {
     return [
         'NombreResultado.required' => __('NombreResultado.required'),
         'ArchivoResultado.required' => __('ArchivoResultado.required'),
         'ArchivoResultado.file' => __('ArchivoResultado.file'),
         'ArchivoResultado.mimes' => __('ArchivoResultado.mimes'),
         'ArchivoResultado.max' => __('ArchivoResultado.max')
      ];
     }
 }
```

`NombreResultado.required` required rule is validating ok, the problem is with `ArchivoResultado.required` it is validating all the rules except for the `required` rule. I’ve tried deleting all the other rules and leaving only that rule but it's not working. This is a `dd` of the `$validacionResultado` in the controller when i submit the form without the file:

```
 array:1 [
       "NombreResultado" => array:1 [
         0 => "Name of the file"
       ]
 ]
```

This is a `dd` with the file attached:

```
array:2 [
   "NombreResultado" => array:1 [
     0 => "Name of the file"
   ]
   "ArchivoResultado" => array:1 [
     0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1328
       -test: false
       -originalName: "factura_00000525.pdf"
       -mimeType: "application/pdf"
       -error: 0
       #hashName: null
       path: "/private/var/tmp"
       filename: "phpoVUvWV"
       basename: "phpoVUvWV"
       pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpoVUvWV"
       extension: ""
       realPath: "/private/var/tmp/phpoVUvWV"
       aTime: 2021-03-13 04:53:56
       mTime: 2021-03-13 04:53:56
       cTime: 2021-03-13 04:53:56
       inode: 80503611
       size: 136213
       perms: 0100600
       owner: 70
       group: 0
       type: "file"
       writable: true
       readable: true
       executable: false
       file: true
       dir: false
       link: false
     }
   ]
 ]
```

i'm not attaching a `dd` of `$resultadoRequest` because it's too long. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `$this-redirect = url()-previous();` is missing `>`: `$this->redirect = url()->previous();`. As well as `$examenRequest-validated()` and `$resultadoRequest-validated()`

Comment: it was an error when i was trying to post the code, stackoverflow was giving me an error in the code formatting, i had to remove all the >

Comment: Don't _type_ your code here, copy/paste it, works like a charm and prevents typos. Is `=>` in `$validacionExamen => $examenRequest->validated();` another typo? I'm out

Answer (score 1):

You want to check that the array of files is present and not empty, then check each file in the array. You already have the part that checks each file in the array, so add the check of array itself.

```
 return [
     'NombreResultado.*' => 'required|string',
     'ArchivoResultado' => 'required|array',
     'ArchivoResultado.*' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf|max:1024',
 ];
```

Comment: This do the trick if only 1 file is submitted, but when i submit multiple files it skips the required rule. if i check the submit it is submitting 2 name arrays and 1 file array

Comment: it doesn't skip the required rule, your requirement is just different to what required means. To validate whether the number of names and files match, you will have to write custom validation.

Comment: Or you can change the structure of your input to be an array of name and file that way you can validate each element to ensure there's both a name and file submitted